# Get outgoing IP address in Java RMI

Tags: java, ip-address, rmi

In my java RMI application, I can have instances that behave as servers both locally and on different hosts. In the latter case, how can I get my outgoing IP address so that I can set it as the argument of system property java.rmi.server.hostName?

Right now it's hard wired, but that's not a desirable solution.

Comment: Consider that the outgoing host IP may not be what the client sees if the server is behind a NAT firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the classic Java way:

```
try {
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

    // Get IP Address
    byte[] ipAddr = addr.getAddress();

    // Get hostname
    String hostname = addr.getHostName();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you think you need this. The source-address in outgoing stubs is set to the host's IP address automatically. The only time you need to set this property is if the default setting isn't correct: e.g. if you have multiple NICs and only want to export via one, or if you have the Linux misconfiguration that maps your hostname to 127.0.0.1 instead of your IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The following will display all available non-loopback IPv4 adresses on a host. You can easily adapt it to get IPv6 addresses as well.

```
public static void main(String...args) {
  List<InetAddress> addresses = getNonLocalIPV4Addresses();
  for (InetAddress addr: addresses) {
    System.out.println("address: " + addr.getHostAddress());
  }
}

/**
 * Get a list of all known non-local IP v4 addresses for the current host.
 * @return a List of <code>InetAddress</code>, may be empty but never null.
 */
public static List<InetAddress> getNonLocalIPV4Addresses() {
  return getIPAddresses(new InetAddressFilter() {
    public boolean accepts(InetAddress addr) {
      return (addr instanceof Inet4Address)
        && !(addr.isLoopbackAddress()) || "localhost".equals(addr.getHostName()));
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get a list of all known IP addresses for the current host,
 * according to the specified filter.
 * @param filter filters out unwanted addresses.
 * @return a List of <code>InetAddress</code>, may be empty but never null.
 */
public static List<InetAddress> getIPAddresses(InetAddressFilter filter) {
  List<InetAddress> list = new ArrayList<InetAddress>();
  try {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces =
      NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
      NetworkInterface ni = interfaces.nextElement();
      Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = ni.getInetAddresses();
      while (addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
        InetAddress addr = addresses.nextElement();
        if ((filter == null) || filter.accepts(addr)) list.add(addr);
      }
    }
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return list;
}

/**
 * Filter interface for the methods discovering available IP addresses. 
 */
public interface InetAddressFilter {
  /**
   * Determine whether the specified address is accepted.
   * @param addr the address to check.
   * @return true if the address is accepted, false otherwise.
   */
  boolean accepts(InetAddress addr);
}
```